# grunt-contrib-imagemin output "Fatal error: ENOENT, no such file or directory"

Tags: image, image-processing, gruntjs

The command `grunt imagemin` output the following to a random file.

```
Fatal error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'app/public/assets/img/epg/recordseries.png'
```

What's funny is that each time I run the command grunt imagemin again, it manages to process a few more files and ends by outputting the same error about another file.

I'm using

```
node v0.10.24
npm 1.3.21
grunt@0.4.2
grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin
+-- filesize@2.0.0
+-- async@0.2.9
+-- chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.2, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
+-- image-min@0.1.2 (mkdirp@0.3.5, cache-file@0.1.2, mout@0.7.1, optipng-bin@0.3.1, jpegtran-bin@0.2.3, gifsicle@0.1.4)
```

Here is my grunt config for `imagemin` task:

```js
grunt.config('imagemin', {
    options: {
        optimizationLevel: 3, // 0 to 7, default =7)
        // pngquant: true
    },
    dynamic: {                                          // Multiple target
        files: [{
            expand: true,                               // Enable dynamic expansion
            cwd: '<%= context.source %>/assets/img/',   // equal to app/wesource/assets/img/
            src: ['!**/*-'+arrayToRegexStr(platformIgnoreList)+'**', '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}'],                // Actual patterns to match //
            dest: '<%= context.public %>/assets/img/'   // equal to app/public/assets/img/
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Uninstalling version 0.5.0 and going back to version 0.3.0 with the following commands should restore the prior functionality:

```
npm uninstall grunt-contrib-imagemin

npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.3.0
```

There is an issue, https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/140, that is being worked on, and when it is fixed it should be safe to upgrade.

Comment: Version 0.6.0 has been released.

Answer (score 3):

The following solutions works on...

- Ubuntu Linux 13.10 x64
- npm --version = 1.3.11
- node --version = v0.10.21
- grunt-contrib-imagemin = 0.5.0

This is a hack of a solution, but I found the task fails when it looks at the the target directory to see if the PNG image already exists and is optimized. The task would consistently finish when I ran it over and over, each time it would complete a few more images. And I could repeat the problem by running `grunt clean`, then `grunt imagemin` over and over.

The error I saw was:

`bash
Fatal error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'build-production/path-to/some-image.png'`

## Solution

Copy the images to the target dir immediately before optimizing them. This way, the check passes and unoptimized images that are copied are replaced by their optimized equivalent.

### task

```
grunt.task.run(
    'copy:imagemin',
    'imagemin'
);
```

### copy configuration

```
copy: {
    imagemin: {
        files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= exponential.client.src %>',
                src: ['images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: '<%= exponential.client.buildProduction %>'
        }]
    }
}
```

### imagemin configuration

```
imagemin: {
    buildProduction: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= exponential.client.src %>',
            src: ['images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            dest: '<%= exponential.client.buildProduction %>'
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: That do the trick but I'm ending up with another error ```Warning: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50 Use --force to continue.``` on a particular images optimized before that one are empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use
`cache: false`

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling `optipng`that I had accidentally installed system wide.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Thanks for the answer, saved me a buttload of time debugging.

Comment: Same here, thanks. I needed to uninstall `optipng-bin` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with grunt-contrib-imagemin and it was because I was running grunt with sudo.

My fix was to do a chown and a chmod on the entire structure then run grunt without sudo...

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was a clean install of the node modules
I remove the node_modules dir and did npm install
after that it worked again for me