# grunt-yui-compressor output “Fatal error: ENOENT, no such file or directory”

Tags: gruntjs, yui-compressor

**'grunt min' / 'grunt cssmin' command not working properly**

```
Fatal error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\wamp\www\git\static4\101\1414392570694'
```

When i run 'grunt min' / 'grunt cssmin' command, each time after some succussfull minifciation operation i got the above mentioned error.

```
versions which i use:
node v0.10.32
npm 1.4.28
grunt-yui-compressor : grunt-yui-compressor@0.3.3
```

> Below is my grunt config for js and css min task:

```
grunt.mergeConfig({
   min: {
         jsFiles : {
          files: [
            {
              expand: true,
              cwd: 'src/j/',
              src: ['**/*.js'],
              dest: 'gen/j',
              ext: '.min.js',
              extDot: 'last'
            },
          ],
      }
    },

    cssmin: {
        cssFiles : {
          files: [
            {
              expand: true,
              cwd: 'src/c',
              src: ['**/*.css'],
              dest: 'gen/c',
              ext: '.min.css',
              extDot: 'last'
            },
          ],
      }
    }
});
grunt.registerTask('min');
grunt.registerTask('cssmin');
```

this is similar to [this One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175673/grunt-contrib-imagemin-output-fatal-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory), but i am facing the same in grunt-yui-compressor.

Waiting for any valuable solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)